# Data being truncated when inserted into DB from UI web application

Tags: .net, oracle, clob, varchar2

My code behind on the .net application uses `System.Data.OracleClient`, which I realize is deprecated.

What I'm wondering is if I have a 2000 CHARACTER entry in my asp:text box, about how many bytes do I need in my database to handle the entry?  I know that 1 character sometimes = 1 byte, but in this case, the encoding seems to be adding extra bytes which causes the message to be truncated.  I do NOT receive an error from the DB or the application when this occurs.

To resolve this issue, do I need to make my varchar2(4000) datafields CLOBS in order to handle data entries by the user?

Thank you for any tips and advice.

Comment: What character set is used in your database?  Run the following query: `SELECT value$ FROM sys.props$ WHERE name = 'NLS_CHARACTERSET'` - although, thinking about it, that shouldn't matter too much (although good info to know).  If the data you were inserting was too long for the field an exception would be thrown - should be something like `ORA-12899: value too large for column`.

Comment: You can try using the latest Oracle Data Adapter
 http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/index-085163.html

Comment: Regarding your question, how are you passing the data to the backend (e.g. stored procedure, SQL statement in .Net,...?)

Comment: Using a stored proceedure.  I've double checked to make sure that the stored proceedure uses the correct datatype (in fact, the stored proceedure always takes the datatype of the underlying table).